# How to enable the google free widgets to work with https?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, https, google-gadget

I use Google free [gadgets](http://www.google.com/webmasters/gadgets/foryourpage/index.html) in my web site .

every thing goes okay when my web application use `http`. if i use `https` then these widgets don't appear at all .

---

Is there some configuration to allow the widgets to appear through secure `http`

---

I embed code like the following in my web page  :

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.gstatic.com/ig/modules/datetime_v2/kennedy/datetime_v2.xml&amp;up_color=grey&amp;up_dateFormat=wmd&amp;up_firstDay=0&amp;up_clocks=%5B%5D&amp;up_mainClock=&amp;up_mainClockTimeZoneOffset=&amp;up_mainClockDSTOffset=&amp;up_24hourClock=true&amp;up_showWorldClocks=true&amp;up_useServerTime=false&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=160&amp;title=__MSG_title__&amp;lang=en&amp;country=ALL&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but I don't have sufficient rep to add this as a comment to your question. You might find some hints in the console of your browser (under developer's tools).

Comment: Out of curiosity. What if you use **https** `url` parameter in the `src` of your script (`//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=https://www.gstatic...`)? I don't have a secure server at hand to try it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if I make the following change it works for me on my server:

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/i.... etc.
```

put http: in front of the //

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/i.... etc.
```

Of course using this method you will lose the 'magic' that src="// provides. AND, there may be warnings about non SSL content on the secure page.

EDIT:

Doing a little more digging, it appears that the SSL certificate for gmodules.com is untrusted and a secure connection cannot be made. The link proffered by Joe leads to the 2009 article dealing with a similar issue.

I think this is something to be fixed by google. Any work-around that I can think of seems way over the top for a gadget. Failing google putting a valid certificate on their website or hosting this service on a google.com domain not sure they is much that can be done.